# Add image in Ribbon title (in VSTO)?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, ribbonx

I build a VSTO. Is it possible to add an image (or icon) in the text of the custom Ribbon (tab) name, like this image:

[image]

I even can't change the ribbon title(from `ribbon`.cs) with :

```
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        myRibbon.Label = "something";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Ribbon XML schema does not support / allow images in the "Tab" region of the Ribbon.

Comment: thanks! and what about that I can't change the label text or anything at all after `ribbon-load` ?

Comment: @T.Todua Please ask a new question for a new topic and include more detail, such as an example of what you mean, whether you're using the Ribbon Designer or Ribbon XML in the VSTO solution, etc.

Comment: here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257273/change-ribbon-menu-properties-after-ribbon-load   . with regard to this current topic, so I cant anyway inject image there, right?

Comment: @T.Todua I'll look at it when I have time. No, there's no way to put an image in the Tab section of the Ribbon. Period.