# Change Ribbon-menu properties after ribbon-load

Tags: ms-office, vsto, ribbonx

I build a VSTO (made with the Ribbon Designer, not using Ribbon XML). Is it possible to change the properties (like label) of the Tab from `Ribbon1.cs` ?

I even can't change the ribbon title with :

```
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        myRibbon.Label = "something";
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you mean the `Tab` label? A Ribbon does not have a `Label` property and it's not clear what you'd be trying to change with that. Also, the code you show us is changing a property when the Ribbon loads, but the title of the question says "after ribbon-load". Which do you mean? Please be as accurate and detailed as possible.

Comment: @CindyMeister sorry, yes, I mean Tab label

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this dynamically is using a callback.

In your ribbon XML:

```
<tab id="myTabID" getLabel="myCallback">
  ....
</tab>
```

In your ribbon code:

```
public string myCallback(IRibbonControl control)
{
    switch (control.Id)
    {
        case "myTabID":
            return "My Label";
        case "whatever else":
        default:
            return "n/a";
    }
}
```

The callback will execute whenever the tab is displayed, so probably on startup. When you actually want to change what's showing, you have to invalidate it:

```
ribbon.Invalidate();
// or
ribbon.InvalidateControl(id);
```